# SqlServer Oracle linked server cannot see tables in the default schema

Tags: sql-server, oracle

In Sql Management Studio (2012) I have set up a linked Oracle server which works fine.  However, I cannot see or access any tables that are in the default schema (i.e., which do not have a schema name).

In other words I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (LinkName)..(SchemaName).(TableName)
```

but I can't do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (LinkName)...(TableName)
```

These tables also do not show up under the Linked Server tables folder, and doing a select returns the error "The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table."

I know the tables are there and I have the appropriate rights because I can see and access these tables when working with SSIS on the same machine, and with the same credentials.

Any ideas?

Comment: In SQL Server > Server Objects > Providers make sure your OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is allowing inprocessing

Comment: All tables in Oracle belong to a schema/user - there is no default schema. If you are logged in with a user then Oracle will assume you are using that user's schema unless you specify another schema - however everything I have briefly read for SQL server linked servers has used the fully qualified `schemaname.tablename` when querying tables. Are you logged in with the correct user?

Comment: There are two "default" schemas in Oracle (if they can be called that), and they are accessed when you log in with a specific *privilege*. They are the **`SYS`** schema, accessed with `connect <user> AS SYSDBA`, and the **`PUBLIC`** schema, accessed `AS SYSOPER`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-2033E766-8FE6-4FBA-97E0-2607B083FA2C.htm#ADMQS12004

Comment: To WEI_DBA: Yes - the inprocess flag is turned on

Comment: To mathguy: maybe "default schema" is the wrong terminology from the Oracle perspective.  The issue is that some of the Oracle tables in the database I am going after do not have a schema name, and those are the ones that I cannot see or access via the SqlServer linked server function.  I tried using both "SYS" and "PUBLIC" as schema names, but that didn't work either.

Comment: To MT0: I am logged in with the correct user, because when I do Oracle access via an SSIS job I use the same credentials, and can see all of the tables, including those that do not have a schema name associated with them.